# How to run python program (or other cmd) with docker dependencies?

Tags: python, docker

I have some python package `utils` in container `./utils`, and some other dependencies, but I have a python program `start.py` which I want to run in host machine.

Is there any way to do it? We can consider the scenario is that the `start.py` is in host machine which could be easier to use by user and the dependencies are in docker(no need for user to build)

Comment: Are you open to the suggestion of mounting the python script an ephemeral container and then run it?

Comment: I think @7_R3X's answer makes the most sense here, but just out of curiosity why do this in the first place?  It seems like an usual problem to have, and perhaps there is a better way in the first place...

Comment: @Iguananaut: I'd agree with you. Such problems should not arise while using Docker. The architecture could be better designed.

Comment: @7_R3X  Yes I am also considering a better solution in the first place. In brief, this is a common case that, 1) the environment need to be prepared easily. 2) the entrance of the program (api) should be easy to run and api could use the environment (if in container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount the `start.py` onto an ephemeral container and then run the python script inside the container. If the script produces an output that needs to be stored on the host, you can mount the output's location too.

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint 'python /tmp/start.py' -v <location of script on host>:/tmp/start.py -v <location where you want to store output on host>:<location where output is stored inside the container> <image_name>
```

Comment: oh so the bindmounting volume shares all the corresponding contents, it the one is run in host, it would also run in container?

Comment: @Litchy No, the python script is actually running inside the container and not on the host. But, we can take the file from the host and store the script's output back to the host using this.

Comment: Okay, my understanding of your words is, when the python script is bindmounted to the container, and the running command runs it in the host, it would not run in the host, but the container takes it and run it in the container?

Comment: @Litchy Yes. The file is now accessible to the container and the container can now run it. But, since the file is bind-mounted on to the container, it won't be deleted when the container gets deleted.